# Database design for sensor capturing. NoSQL vs SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database-design, cassandra, nosql

I'm struggling to design a fast query DB.
I have several factories capturing data from 50 to 500 sensors each every 2 seconds and stored in ROWS for every sensor.
You can imagine the volume of data going from 2,16M to 21,6M rows per day and factory.
I have to work with .NET, that part I can't change.

Until now the data was stored in SQL Server Express 08R2 in each factory, then send to the main server SQL Server 08R2 every hour and stored in individual database per factory. The design used now is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CalculatedValues](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, -- not useful at all.
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Var] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_CalculatedValues] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
    ( [ID] ASC )WITH (...) ON [PRIMARY] 
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CalculatedValues_Date_Var] ON [dbo].[CalculatedValues] 
    ( [Date] DESC, [Var] ASC )WITH (...) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The values can be DECIMAL or BIT(boolean), so that part may change too.

It was working somehow fine for the desktop application, having to generate reports in worst case scenario for the last three months. (it takes around 3 MINUTES)

Now a web application is required and you can imagine that the reports must be generated in milliseconds instead of seconds. Report cannot be pre-generated since the user may choose dates from X to Y.

I was considering to keep up with SQL Server or change to single node Cassandra ( even knowing 3 nodes is the minimum to unleash Cassandra's benefits ).

My question is: How do I redesign this?
Values cannot be grouped, so no normalization can be applied.
I was thinking for something like this:

```
TABLE CalculatedValues(
    Date datetime PK,
    ValueSensor01 DECIMAL,
    ValueSensor02 BIT,
    ValueSensor03 DECIMAL,
    ....
)
```

But how fast will be to extract 300/500 columns from almost 4M rows? It'll be faster in NoSQL (Cassandra or any other compatible with .NET) or SQL Server?

I accept all kind of suggestions.

Thank you very much.

EDIT01: Queries go only by DATE and Var as you can see in the declared Index. Every factory has different kind of queries, since almost all the sensors are different.

Comment: Too broad for a Q&A format.

Comment: I think the statement "Now a web application is required and you can imagine that the reports must be generated in milliseconds instead of seconds" is mistaken.  There are many web applications that take some time to return a response and this is fine if you use a "Calculating...", "Results available" pattern.  I have an application that accepts report requests via a web form and emails the result as that was most useful to the people requesting the reports.

Comment: You need to specify your query. **How** do you want to fetch the data ? By sensor_id and by range of date ? Only by range of what no matter the sensor id ? etc ...

Comment: Some terms for you to Google: Streaming databases; Process historian; Time series data. There are lots of software tools and techniques to support precisely your kind of scenario.

Comment: Thank you for you responses. I'll research further and make and feedback for latest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I’m working right now with Azure SQL and DocumentDB (noSQL) at the same time. 
I’m talking about DocumentDB, but I assume it’s moe or less the same with others .Net NoSQL providers.

There are my insights:

1. Inserts are WAAAAY faster with documentDB (Even if documentDB is S1 tier (cheapest) and SQL is Premium 1 (one of the most expensive)
2. Retrieve 1 document from DocumentDB is fast. Retrive multiples, is long.. very long
3. There is NO  way to store date in datetime format in DocumentDB (We are using “Epoch” hacking : storing unix timestamp with custom JsonDesirializer)
4. There is NO way to update a document in documentDB (You need to use “replace document”)
5. There is a LOT of limitations in LinQ for DocumentDB

For you needs, I’ll go with high tier (p1-p2) of Azure SQL. If it’s on premise, definitely SQL. Just adjust your indexes and make sure to use SSD and data will flow. (Rule of thumb: you need as much RAM as your biggest database, if possible)

Edit : For report part : Stored procedures and caching is a way to go. Going to store procedures from EntityFramework cut loading time from 40 seconds to 2 seconds for our application

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I'll try some of that and do the feedback here.